# Calculating internal energy of fragment from $D_0$, photon energy and interval energy + velocity of other fragment

Tags: physical-chemistry, photochemistry

I am trying to solve the following:

We consider a photodissociation of a molecule into two fragments. The energy available to the products can be calculated from the bond dissociation energy and the photon energy. If the internal energy and the center-of-mass recoil velocity of one fragment is known, how can you find the internal energy of the second fragment? (use conservation of momentum and energy)

So I know that [energy available to products]=[photon energy]-[bond dissociation energy]. But my problem is that I am not sure what [energy available to products] consists of. Is it the sum internal energies of the two fragments plus the sum of the kinetic energies of the two fragments?

Can someone shed some light one this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: I haven't thought about this closely enough to answer definitively, but I know it is possible to measure $D_0$ using velocity-map imaging (which manages to send fragments of the same velocity to the same point on a detector, hence determining product distribution of COM kinetic energy). One then combines this with pre-dissociation techniques where one excites a particular vibrational mode before dissociation so that fragment vibrational energy is known. The energy available to products is translational, rotational, and vibrational energy (ignoring electronic excitation).

Comment: See [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.3598339?showFTTab=true&containerItemId=content%2Faip%2Fjournal%2Fjcp) about measuring $D_0$ of $\ce{(H2O)2}$ for more info